# Cakephp 4 Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-4.x

In cakephp 4 and in this ajax function the the beforeSend's alert message has been displayed in the browser but the request is not sent to the server.Both success and error are not working.

Finally this ajax function is not at all working.There is no any error in console or there is no any request sent in the network tab of the browser but beforeSend is working.

What may be the problem ?
Its been couple of months when we got this error but not able to figure out whats the problem is , please let me know if any one has the solution.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "kalyan/ajaxRequest",
  type: "POST",
  data: postcontent,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    // Set the CSRF token in the request headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
    alert("CSRF Token: " + csrfToken);
  },
  success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("Yay!");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
    alert(response);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    console.error("Error:", errorThrown);
  },
});
```

I was expecting any error or success message to be shown in the console but nothing has been.

Comment: What triggers this code to run? Could it be triggered by an event that causes navigation to happen? Perhaps you just need `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Your browser console is a good starting point to start with, check if it does there are any errors on the client-side, and if not, check the network tab to check the AJAX call response

Comment: Thanks for your replay I tried these things but the main problem is there is no any error in console and also there is not any request occuring in the network tab.Only the beforeSend method is executing.

Comment: No obvious reason apparent here, why the request should not happen. Not sure if "blocking" `alert` statements can interfere with this somehow; I'd recommend that you replace thos by console.log statements first of all. _"Its been couple of months when we got this error"_ - you mean, _all_ the time, or just occasionally?

Comment: occasionally we were trying to solve this.I tried by console.log but only that before send's message has been displayed in the console.

Comment: I recommend if you have no already to enable the "Preserve log" option in both the _Console_ and _Network_ dev-tools panels. I still think this is being cancelled due to navigation

Comment: Yes, but the before send method in the code is executed.